# Time complexity of Code

Tags: complexity-theory

4. The running time of for/while loop is number of iterations * running time of statement

   Sum=0
   for (i=0; i< n; i++)
   For (j=0;j

Please help me Guys everyone is Saying it's complexity is O (n^5)  I'm Stuck..

Comment: This is not a homework service

Answer (score -2):

"Sum=0 for (i=0; i< n; i++) For (j=0;j " is not finished so we can only guess whats following. In case its Sum=0 for(i=0; i< n; i++) For (j=0;j < n;j++) then its complexity is n^2 since you are doing the second loop n times and the second loop goes through n iterations so you get n^2. Just to clarify a bit in the case of : for(i=0; i< n; i++) For ( j=0 ;j < y ; j++ ) , the complexity would be n * y.

Comment: You're not supposed to guess what the question is. Post a comment or just ignore the question.